# How to mock activity dependencies in an instrumentation test

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, android-testing

I want to get a reference to my activity before it is created in order to inject some mocks.

So I have my activity test rule like:

```
   ActivityTestRule mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity,class, true, false)
```

I know that ActivityTestRule has a beforeActivityLaunched callback, but there I cant get any reference to my activity (is null there).

So if I do:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule(
        MainActivity.class) {
    @Override
    protected void beforeActivityLaunched() {
        super.beforeActivityLaunched();
        MainActivity act = (MainActivity)getActivity();
         //Here act is null
```

I cannot get a reference to my activity in the setUp method of my test class either. Activity reference is ready only when I do rule.launchActivity(), but then Activity is executed and I cannot pass any dependencies before. I know that I can use dagger for that, but I want to avoid it for this case. Is there any way to prepare the activity dependencies without dagger before it is launched?

Comment: This is a good question because it is exactly this pattern that is required when making use of Espresso Idling Resources that are acquired and released by an activity yet having the IdlingRegistry register() and unregister() called by the ActivityRule.  In my case the Activity lifecycle methods interacted with the Idling Resource (conditionally on the resource not being null) and my hope was to set the resource before lifecycle transitions.  In the end I had to redesign the Activity to fit the testing model...

Answer (score -1):

If the second parameter (launchActivity) is false in ActivityTestRule it means you should customize the intent per test method

```
@Test
public void dummyTest() {
  mActivityRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
 // code here
}
```